# Writing to and reading from an ArrayList using java with NetBeans GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

What im trying to code is for a college project where I am creating an app using NetBeans, where I am adding information about players in the ryder cup. I have text fields for all the variables(team, name, dob, home, college, prof, years, matches, won, captain, pga, champion and intern) on my GUI, when I get the GUI to save and read properly I will add in all the info about all my players, then ill delete the text fields and the save button.

What I want the whole page to do is when the user clicks a radio button for either team usa or team europe, all the info about the players in that team will appear. Im thinking of using labels to display each players info.

So for now I am stuck on the save and read part. When I add in the info for the first player and save it, it works. But if I add in another players info, it will only read the first players info. I am not sure how to get it to save to the next array list and not on top of the first array list object.

I hope I have made it clear what I am trying to do. I would greatly appreciate any help, Thank you!

```
//my instantiable class code

package rydercup;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class players implements Serializable {

    private String team;
    private String name;
    private String dob;//date of birth and age
    private String home;//hometown
    private String college;
    private String prof;//turned professional 
    private String years;//years played
    private String matches;//total matches
    private String won;//total points won
    private String captain;//team usa captain years 
    private String pga;//PGA tour
    private String champion;//champions tour victories
    private String intern;//international victories

    public players() {
        team = new String();
        name = new String();
        dob = new String();
        home = new String();
        college = new String();
        prof = new String();
        years = new String();
        matches = new String();
        won = new String();
        captain = new String();
        pga = new String();
        champion = new String();
        intern = new String();
    }

    public void setTeam(String team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public void setHome(String home) {
        this.home = home;
    }

    public void setCollege(String college) {
        this.college = college;
    }

    public void setProf(String prof) {
        this.prof = prof;
    }

    public void setYears(String years) {
        this.years = years;
    }

    public void setMatches(String matches) {
        this.matches = matches;
    }

    public void setWon(String won) {
        this.won = won;
    }

    public void setCaptain(String captain) {
        this.captain = captain;
    }

    public void setPga(String pga) {
        this.pga = pga;
    }

    public void setChampion(String champion) {
        this.champion = champion;
    }

    public void setIntern(String intern) {
        this.intern = intern;
    }




    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public String getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public String getHome() {
        return home;
    }

    public String getCollege() {
        return college;
    }

    public String getProf() {
        return prof;
    }

    public String getYears() {
        return years;
    }

    public String getMatches() {
        return matches;
    }

    public String getWon() {
        return won;
    }

    public String getCaptain() {
        return captain;
    }

    public String getPga() {
        return pga;
    }

    public String getChampion() {
        return champion;
    }

    public String getIntern() {
        return intern;
    }
}

//my GUI code
package rydercup;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class RyderPlayer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    //variables
    private ArrayList <players> usaList;
    private String team, name, dob, home, college, prof, years, matches, won;
    private String captain, pga, champion, intern;
    private int count;

    public RyderPlayer() {
        initComponents();
        usaList = new ArrayList <> ();
        team = new String();
        name = new String();
        dob = new String();
        home = new String();
        college = new String();
        prof = new String();
        years = new String();
        matches = new String();
        won = new String();
        captain = new String();
        pga = new String();
        champion = new String();
        intern = new String();
        //initialise count to 0
        count = 0;
    }


    //generate code ....  


    private void saveBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

        File outFile;
        FileOutputStream fStream;
        ObjectOutputStream oStream;

        try{
            outFile = new File("usa.data");
            fStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            oStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fStream);

            oStream.writeObject(usaList);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File written successfully");

            oStream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }                                       





   private void readBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

        File inFile;
        FileInputStream fStream;
        ObjectInputStream oStream;

        try{
            inFile = new File("usa.data");
            fStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
            oStream = new ObjectInputStream(fStream);

            ArrayList <players> xList;
            xList = (ArrayList<players>)oStream.readObject();
            for(players x:xList){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Team: "+x.getTeam()   +  
                                                "\n Name: "+x.getName()  +  
                                                "\n Date of birth: "+x.getDob()  +  
                                                "\n Home: "+x.getHome()  +  
                                                "\n College: "+x.getCollege()  +  
                                                "\n Turned Professional:"+x.getProf()  +   
                                                "\n Years played: "+x.getYears()  +  
                                                "\n Total matches: "+x.getMatches()  +  
                                                "\n Total points won: "+x.getWon()  +  
                                                "\n USA captain years: "+x.getCaptain()  +   
                                                "\n PGA tour: "+x.getPga()  +  
                                                "\n Champion tour: "+x.getChampion()  +  
                                                "\n International: "+x.getIntern());
            }

            oStream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }


    //generate code ....

}
```

Comment: I do not have Java in front of me, so I need more description about your problem to help you. But remember, usaList is always empty in your code. Also, xList gets a single element. You could use ArrayList<ArrayList<players>> instead of ArrayList<players> and add the element to xList instead of assigning the value to xList.

Comment: I think there is something in your code you are not showing us.  From what I see so far, you should be able to iterate over the xList while displaying all Players that have been saved to file. The behaviour you describe is not reflected in your code.